# How to list pages by date using Jekyll last_modified_at

Tags: for-loop, jekyll, last-modified

I use `last_modified_at` to generate and display the date that a given page was last updated.

Now, I'm trying to create a list of pages sorted *by* `last_modified_at`

Since it is calculated on the fly, it needs to be inside of the `{% for %}` loop.

Therefore the following doesn't work:

`{% assign page_list = site.pages | sort: 'last_modified_at' %}`

I believe I need to create an entirely new hash where the date has already been calculated and stored so I can iterate over *that* set of data, which would basically be a duplicate.

**Question**: How would one do such a thing?

Comment: You can see the data here:  https://newvalleyresources.com/pagelist.html

Comment: Did you try splitting your code? `{% assign page_list = site.pages %}` and `{{ page_list | sort: 'last_modified_at' }}`

Comment: The problem is that `{{ page_list }}` has a bunch of strange data listed in the field that would normally result in the date.  And, if I reference `{{ page.last_modified_at }}` I do in fact get the date...despite the rest of the garbage in the value pair for that key.